# Finding the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^2-1}$

Tags: calculus

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone. Turns out I was just making an arithmetic error. Whoops!

Question answered

I've got this infinite series which starts at k=2

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^2-1}$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinite+sum+1%2F(k%5E2-1)

I thought this series might be telescoping, so I decomposed it to:
1/2(k-1) - 1/2(k+1). Then I wrote out partial sums and found that after k=4, terms begin to cancel.

Then I summed up the parts that don't cancel and got the sum = 7/12.

However according to wolfram, the sum is 3/4. I don't understand what I'm missing.

If following my work in text form is confusing, I will gladly write it out and upload a picture.

Comment: Looks like the series starts as $ \frac 12 - \frac 16 +\frac 14 -\frac 18 +\frac 16 \cdots$ so the terms which don't cancel are $\frac 12+\frac 14$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hint on computing the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624203/hint-on-computing-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n2-1) and for example [find $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698963/find-sum-k-2-infty-frac1k2-1)

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^2-1}x^{k-1}$$
then one has
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k+1}x^{k-2},(x^3f'(x))'=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}x^{k}=\frac{x^2}{1-x}.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
f(1)&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{t^3}\int_0^t\frac{x^2}{1-x}dxdt\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_0^t\frac{x^2}{t^3(1-x)}dxdt\\
&=&\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac{x^2}{t^3(1-x)}dtdx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{1-x}\int_x^1 t^{-3}dtdx\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^1(1+x)dx\\
&=&\frac34.
\end{eqnarray}